# Step by step instructions for moving linux to a smaller hard drive?

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy, esxi

### Background:

I have several VMs running debian-wheezy on a home ESXi server box with a free license.

When I first set them up, being a newb, I grossly overestimated the disk space requirements for each, and used the pre-allocated ("thick"?) option.

So, now I want to migrate these VMs to smaller disks, and I've already established that there's no automated way to do this with the free license (incl. Veeam Backup).

I can create a new vdisk of the desired size for each vm, mount it, partition it, etc, but I'm piecing this stuff together from dozens of web pages; I haven't found a single step-by-step set of instructions.

### Question:

Does anyone know if there are step-by-step instructions for migrating a linux installation to a smaller hard drive anywhere?

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or **learning material recommendations are off-topic** because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Comment: I seem to run afoul of the guidelines most times that I need Linux help and post a question here. Is there a better place for questions like mine? (oops, there I go again)

Comment: If you're looking for tutorials, Google and product forums are a good place to look.  Then, if you get stuck on a specific problem while following the tutorial, come back here with that specific question.  That's more how the SE sites work -- we're not here to point you someplace else.  Perhaps edit your question and rephrase it to be about dealing with the problem of migrating to the smaller disks (include system config info and info on what you've tried already, etc.), instead of asking for a tutorial (or a tool to do it for you).

Comment: And then request it be reopened. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to migrate the data to new disks. You can just shrink the partitions, either using a graphic tool such as `gparted` (more on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data)), or via the commandline using `resize2fs` (see for example [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41088/how-do-i-determine-the-new-size-for-resize2fs) or [this howto](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions)).

After you've done that the ESXi server should be able to shrink the vmdk. The VMware knowledge base explains this [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=10185).

**NOTE: any low level operation on a file system or disk image is inherently dangerous**, so please make backups of all important data (which could be as simple as a copy of the vmdk). Neither I nor any tool you use can be held responsible if data is lost.